# Is it possible to disable MVC OutputCache at a level higher than per controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am decorating my controller like so:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public class ComponentController : Controller
```

This works great for disabling all caching for all of the methods exposed by the controller.

I'd like to apply the same logic at an application level and not on a per-controller basis. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it as a global filter in your global.asax file.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new OutputCacheAttribute { NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*" });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add it as a Global Filter.

In the App_Start folder there is usually a FilterConfig.cs class with a RegisterGlobalFilters method:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        // add your filters here           
    }
}
```

This normally gets called as part of Application_Start in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{            
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
}
```